# Move elements from $pull to another array

Tags: mongodb

I have many documents in the same collection that look like this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("4d525ab2924f0000000022ad"),
  "array": [
    { id: 1, other: 23 },
    { id: 1, other: 21 },
    { id: 0, other: 235 },
    { id: 1, other: 765 }
  ],
  "zeroes": []
}
```

and I want them to look like this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("4d525ab2924f0000000022ad"),
  "array": [
    { id: 1, other: 23 },
    { id: 1, other: 21 },
    { id: 1, other: 765 }
  ],
  "zeroes": [
    { id: 0, other: 235 }
  ]
}
```

Basically, I want to be able to pull some elements in an array, and push it to another array. I know I can use `$pull` to conditionally remove elements from an array, but is it possible to relocate these pulled elements?

Comment: if all elements in zeros will have id = 0, why do you need to have that field? why not to make zeros : [235]

Comment: Sorry, the naming for the zeroes array was misleading. It should actually hold objects with specific ids, not just 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. You can use cursor for operation like this.

```
db.foo.find({}).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.zeros = doc.array.filter(function(x) { return x.id == 0 });
    doc.array = doc.array.filter(function(x) { return x.id != 0 });
    db.foo.save(doc)};
)
```

Comment: I guess there's no other way around this.

Comment: One way or another you'll have to execute some code that cannot be simply expressed using basic MongoDB operators Since it looks like one-time batch job to fix the schema is that really a problem?

Comment: I'd much rather the db handle as much of it as it can, in case something goes wrong on the client and not all documents are updated. Not a huge problem even if that happens though.

Comment: You have to check for error anyway, right? Bigger problem here is that you cannot perform update atomically. If there is write to the document between fetching and writing it will be overwritten.