# Atomically move object by ID from one array to another in same document

Tags: mongodb

I have data that looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("4d525ab2924f0000000022ad"),
  "arrayField": [
    { id: 1, other: 23 },
    { id: 2, other: 21 },
    { id: 0, other: 235 },
    { id: 3, other: 765 }
  ],
  "someOtherArrayField": []
}
```

Given a nested object's ID (`0`), I'd like to `$pull` the element from one array (`arrayField`) and `$push` it to another array (`someOtherArrayField`) within the same document. The result should look like this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("id"), 
  "arrayField": [
    { id: 1, other: 23 },
    { id: 2, other: 21 },
    { id: 3, other: 765 }
  ],
  "someOtherArrayField": [
    { id: 0, other: 235 }
  ]
}
```

I realize that I can accomplish this with a find followed by an update, i.e.

```
db.foo.findOne({"_id": param._id})
.then((doc)=>{
  db.foo.update(
    {
      "_id": param._id
    },
    {
      "$pull": {"arrayField": {id: 0}},
      "$push": {"someOtherArrayField": {doc.array[2]} }
    }
  )
})
```

But I'm looking for an atomic operation like, in pseudocode, this:

```
db.foo.update({"_id": param._id}, {"$move": [{"arrayField": {id: 0}}, {"someOtherArrayField": 1}]}
```

Is there an atomic way to do this, perhaps using MongoDB 4.2's [ability to specify a pipeline to an update command](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-40381)?  How would that look?

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48104435) that generously provided the data I used, but the provided solution isn't an atomic operation. Has an atomic solution become possible with MongoDB 4.2?

Comment: this is an exact duplicate of an existing question - it's better to get an updated answer to the previous question than asking an exact duplicate...

Comment: anything that talks about update is atomic by definition of update.

Comment: I mean the other question literally asks "I was wondering if there's an atomic function that I can do this with"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
> db.baz.find()
> db.baz.insert({
...   "_id": ObjectId("4d525ab2924f0000000022ad"),
...   "arrayField": [
...     { id: 1, other: 23 },
...     { id: 2, other: 21 },
...     { id: 0, other: 235 },
...     { id: 3, other: 765 }
...   ],
...   "someOtherArrayField": []
... })
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

function extractIdZero(arrayFieldName) {
    return {$arrayElemAt: [
        {$filter: {input: arrayFieldName, cond: {$eq: ["$$this.id", 0]}}}, 
        0
    ]};
}

extractIdZero("$arrayField")
{
    "$arrayElemAt" : [
        {
            "$filter" : {
                "input" : "$arrayField",
                "cond" : {
                    "$eq" : [
                        "$$this.id",
                        0
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        0
    ]
}

db.baz.updateOne(
    {_id: ObjectId("4d525ab2924f0000000022ad")},
    [{$set: {
         arrayField: {$filter: {
             input: "$arrayField",
             cond: {$ne: ["$$this.id", 0]}
         }},
         someOtherArrayField: {$concatArrays: [
             "$someOtherArrayField",
             [extractIdZero("$arrayField")]
         ]}
     }}
    ])
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 1 }
> db.baz.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4d525ab2924f0000000022ad"),
    "arrayField" : [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "other" : 23
        },
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "other" : 21
        },
        {
            "id" : 3,
            "other" : 765
        }
    ],
    "someOtherArrayField" : [
        {
            "id" : 0,
            "other" : 235
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The final output shows it was a copy rather than a move.  But I do notice the `{$ne: ["$$this.id", 0]}` filter on `arrayField`. So I guess that's just a typo in the output.

Comment: Good catch @HappyNomad. The $ne was previously wrapped in an array which was a mistake: `[{$ne: ["$$this.id", 0]}]` would always evaluate to `[true]` or `[false]`, which is considered "truthy" either way. Removing the extra brackets fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for demoing these 4.2 improvements! In a similar manner as you showed here, does 4.2 also allow one to atomically move a nested object to an array in a different document? I must support both scenarios, so I'm wondering if there's a common approach that requires only one round-trip to the database.

Comment: I don't know of a way to do that across different documents, other than transactions, which should work well for that scenario.

Comment: can i do this in mongoose?